# Adding Selected State to thumbnail gallery

Tags: jquery

I have been asked to create a thumbnail gallery which changes a main image on click.

I have found this online

jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/frXyP/

However I would like to add a selected state to the thumbnail, so the user knows which thumbnail they are viewing (the thumbnail and the main image wont be the same) and when they click on another thumbnail the selected state is moved from the previous thumbnail to the new one.

Thanking everyone in advance for their help.

Cheers

Cameron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class in your CSS file and toogle it on the click of the thumbnail.. Like this:

```
// precache all images so they will load on demand
var imgs = [];
$('a.thumb').each(function() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = this.href;
    imgs.push(img);
}).click(function () {
    $('a.thumb').removeClass("thumb-active"); // removing the class of all objects
    $(this).addClass("thumb-active"); // Adding the for the active object
    var oldImg = $("#fadeContainer img");

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = this.href;
    var newImg = $(img).hide();
    $("#fadeContainer").append(img);
    oldImg.stop(true).fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
    newImg.fadeIn(500);
   return false;
```

});

In your CSS file, edit the style:

```
.thumb-active{  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response, however I have just tried to insert it into the js fiddle and the selected state is on the last item, rather than the selected state - jsfiddle.net/r8H7X/